# Any way to bold part of a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Is there any way to bold only part of a string?
For example:

> Approximate Distance: **120m** away

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you're displaying it in, because a string is just a series of characters and doesn't contain formatting information.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

What you *could* do is use an [`NSAttributedString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
NSString *yourString = ...;
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName 
                   value:boldFontName
                   range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];
//draw attrString here...
```

Take a look at [this handy dandy guide](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) to drawing `NSAttributedString` objects with Core Text.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what "kCTFontAttributeName" is defined as?

Comment: Oops. just figured that it is a constant that is defined in the CTFont.h in your CoreText framework.

Comment: it says: Use of undefined identifier 'kCTFontAttributeName', did you mean 'NSFontAttributeName'? What's wrong about that? can i use NSFontAttributeName instead?

Comment: @tester Which version of iOS are you building against? I think `NSFontAttributeName` is only available on OS X.

Comment: iOS 6.0, I can't even find kCTFontAttributeName in the class reference of NSMutableAttributedString...

Comment: @tester Just do a symbol search for it, it's in `CTStringAttributes.h`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: for me its not working in ios 7. Can you people guide please.

Comment: This one does not work on iOS7 (crashes with exc_bad_access). The reason for it is you have to send the font instead of the font name as  part of the message. @Chris Frederick does it correctly below.

Comment: addAttribute causes SIGAMRT crash

Comment: Don't forget to add `@import CoreText;` to your code

Comment: NSFontAttributeName is used not to have any crashes, and then you do not need any imports. Check @Andrew Marin 's answer.

Answer (score 62):

As Jacob mentioned, you probably want to use an `NSAttributedString` or an `NSMutableAttributedString`. The following is one example of how you might do this.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Approximate Distance: 120m away"];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4); // 4 characters, starting at index 22

[string beginEditing];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
           value:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0]
           range:selectedRange];

[string endEditing];
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `Use of Undeclared identifier 'NSFont'` on the `value:` line. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is a great example. You're missing an `@` around the example string after your `initWithString:` method on the first line. :)

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner If you are using iOS, replace `NSFont` with `UIFont`

Comment: I figured it out a while ago; I guess I forgot to delete my comment.

Comment: Saved me! Answer to this question needs to be edited I spent like two hours on this &^%#

Comment: @MichalShatz Sorry about that! I just added an '@' sign to fix the syntax error. ;)

Answer (score 14):

If you do not want to bother with fonts (as not every variation of font contains "Bold"), here is another way to do this.  Please be aware, this is currently only available on OS X...:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:"Approximate Distance: 120m away"];
[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString applyFontTraits:NSBoldFontMask
                      range:NSMakeRange(22, 4)];
[attrString endEditing];
```

Comment: NSBoldFontMask is undeclared for iOS? Any replacement?

Comment: @coolcool1994 - Sorry, not that I'm aware.  I will edit my answer to clarify that this is OS X only trick...

Comment: beginEditing and endEditing are 'Overridden by subclasses to buffer or optimize a series of changes to the receiver’s characters or attributes' and not needed here. Otherwise, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Probably helpful here: you can get a mutable copy of an `NSAttributedString *string` instance by calling `[string mutableCopy]`.

Answer (score 6):

The code above gave me crash when I created UILabel with this attributedString.

I used this code and it worked:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
UIFont *fontText = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]; //[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:12];
NSDictionary *dictBoldText = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontText, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[attrString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:boldedRange];
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift**

Also includes getting the range of the string you want to embolden dynamically

```
let nameString = "Magoo"
let string = "Hello my name is \(nameString)"

let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
let boldAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)

let nsString = NSString(string: string)
let range = nsString.rangeOfString(nameString)

if range.length > 0 { attributedString.setAttributes(boldAttribute, range: range) }

someLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 4):

To bold a string without hardcoding its font, you can use the StrokeWidth attribute with a negative value:

```
let s = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Approximate Distance: 120m away")
s.addAttribute(NSStrokeWidthAttributeName, value: NSNumber(value: -3.0), range: NSRange(22..<26))
```

Answer (score 2):

An `NSString` is just a data container.  It doesn't contain any details about presentation concerns.

It sounds like what you probably want to do is bold part of the `UILabel` that is being used to display your string.  Which I don't think you can do.  But you could always break the UI down into three labels, one for "Approximate Distance:", one for "**120 m**", and one for "away".  Place them in-line with each other and you should get the desired effect.

Another option might be to use a `UIWebView` and a little bit of markup to display your string with embedded formatting information, as discussed here:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin ios you can bold part of a NSString this way:

```
public static NSMutableAttributedString BoldRangeOfString (string str, float fontSize, int startRange, int lengthRange)
    {
        var firstAttributes = new UIStringAttributes {
            Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(fontSize)
        };

        NSMutableAttributedString boldString = new NSMutableAttributedString (str);
        boldString.SetAttributes (firstAttributes.Dictionary, new NSRange (startRange, lengthRange));
        return boldString;
    }
```

and call this method:

```
myLabel = new UILabel (); 
...
myLabel.AttributedText = BoldRangeOfString("my text", fontSize, startRange, lengthRange);
```

Comment: The question was not about Xamarin.

Comment: Xamarin works with same object NSString, the question did not specify which language the answer should be in. I came here looking for Xamarin syntax of doing this. Valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

I coupled @Jacob Relkin and @Andrew Marin answers, otherwise, I got the crashes. Here is the answer for iOS9:

```
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
NSString *yourString = @"Approximate Distance: 120m away";
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName 
                   value:boldFont
                   range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];
```

I took a look at the official documentation: [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/addAttribute:value:range:) and [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Shorter way using Swift5+

```
let labelNotes = UILabel()  //or UITextView(), etc...
let attributedNotes = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bold: some stuff not bold")
attributedNotes.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
labelNotes.attributedText = attributedNotes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hardcode the font or/and the size try this code for bolding full strings:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mainString];
[myString beginEditing];
[myString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName
                         value:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: -3.f]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [mainString length])];
[myString endEditing];
```