# Having multiple color fonts in one sentence in xcode/iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

[image]

I want to implement a feature in my iphone app that does something similar to this.  To have 2 different color fonts in 1 sentence.  I read somewhere on stack overflow about three 20, but three 20 won't work on my app.  I also read something about textview?  but I tried to read the documentation for that, but i didn't really understand.

Anyone have some sample code or any other suggestions??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) is a drop-in replacement for UILabel that will let you have multiple fonts, colors, and styles applied to a single label. All you need to do is pass in an NSAttributedString! It's definitely a lot easier and more performant than loading in something gigantic like Three20 or using a UIWebView.

Comment: It has some memory issues, though.  I notice quite a few leaks when monitoring it in Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

**EDIT**: There are a few posts on SO that provide some guidance in using this class. One such example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring).

Does that help?

Comment: even if this is a label, i can add this?

Comment: No, you have to draw it yourself. I haven't done this, but from what I've read, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few NSAttributedString OpenSource projects on GitHub that allow this sort of thing.

Before NSAttributed string was available we all used a UIWebView and "styled" HTML to achieve the same affect. This may be an option depending on your final needs.