# Attribute ranges of characters in a UItextview with NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have the following text in a `UITextview`

> Hello! 
>   The car to your top right is where you setup your car specifications - don't worry, it takes only 30 seconds and you only ever have to set it up once!

I would like to:

1. bold the "Hello!" and make it a size bigger to 17
2. underline the "only 30 seconds"
3. make the "once!" red.

How do I do this? I have very minimal knowledge with `NSAttributedString` and have had no luck with the documentation.

Thankyou

Comment: I should add the text is not selectable and non editable

Comment: get custom UITextview from https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UITextView

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rfmarkdowntextview

Comment: Possible duplicate of **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring**

Comment: Better you use the webview and make a htmlpage  and set text style in it. or check this link http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/

Comment: hmm the second link iPatel doesnt even compile...and the duplicate link does not help my problem at all. I have text in a textview, how do I attribute it from there?

Comment: is that in IBOutlet, I mean in storyBoard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve this via storyboard, select the UITextView & Goto the Attributes Inspector. then look at the below image

[image]

If in programmatically , Check these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)  && [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring?rq=1):

Comment: This answer is perfect! thankyou so much, I did not know you could edit it so simply like this. Quite dissappointed with the other SO memebers who just downvoted this...

Answer (score 1):

Create Mutable Attributed string, do following steps

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourTextView.text];
```

1) Found `Hello!` range and set font with size

```
NSRange foundRange = [attrString rangeOfString:@"Hello!"];
if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                   value:[[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17] fontName]
                   range:boldedRange];
    [attrString endEditing];
}
```

2) Search range for `only 30 seconds` and set underline style

```
foundRange = [attrString rangeOfString:@"only 30 seconds"];
if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] range:foundRange];
    [attrString endEditing];
}
```

3) Search range for `once!` and set stroke color.

```
foundRange = [attrString rangeOfString:@"once!"];
if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:foundRange];
    [attrString endEditing];
}
```

Finally set attributed string to your textview as

```
yourTextView.attributedText = attrString;
```

**Note:** The above only work with `ios6+.`.

Comment: this is great as well thankyou! but the other answer was just so much more simpler. kudos my friend

Comment: I'm not seeing rangeOfString available to be called on an instance of NSMutableAttributedString in Swift 3