# How to search different substring of NSString and make it Bold

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string as "**xyz pqr** has Invited you to Join **The Game** under **Her** group". the substrings which are in bold colour are in between a bracket like in xml. i want to do the same bold functionality in ios.

Comment: You need to use an `NSAttributeString` (or probably an `NSMutableAttributedString`).

Comment: Show us some `Code`, what have you tried ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to bold part of a NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
NSString *str = @"xyz pqr has Invited you to Join The Game under Her group";
NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:@"xyz pqr"];
NSRange range2 = [str rangeOfString:@"The Game"];
NSRange range3 = [str rangeOfString:@"Her"];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Bold-Font", NSFontAttributeName,nil];
[attributedText setAttributes:attrs range:range1];
[attributedText setAttributes:attrs range:range2];
[attributedText setAttributes:attrs range:range3];
```

You can set this string to `UILabel`.

```
label.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using attributed string.Download the project of the mentioned link which has a good demo app of Attributed string.

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/375