# Display string from Nsarray only if it contains

Tags: ios, nsarray

I am using the following query to check if the strings within a `NSArray` contain a certain word.

I am struggling to then break it down to display only the string that has the `rangeOfString` word.

As you can see it currently displays all the results if the `NSArray` contains the word. How would I single it down further to display only the specific string that contains the `"BOLDME"` ?

```
// change this line only for the concatenation
        NSString * resultConditions = [legislationArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

        NSString *word = @"BOLDME";
        //if string contains
        if ([resultConditions rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {

            cell.dynamicTextView.text = resultConditions;

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display only specific string"?

Comment: @AndrewShmig the NSString that contains the @"BOLDME"

Comment: why not just to iterate over NSArray and check each string if it contains that string? for(NSString *value in array) if([value rangeOfString:word] != NSNotFound) { /* we have found that string*/ }

Comment: Why can't you use a for loop ?

Comment: @MidhunMP so For each string in array do the query? how would I then add them all to the textView?

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone: I'm not clear about your requirement. I think you need to only display all strings which contains that particular word. Right ?

Comment: hi @MidhunMP. To be honest I don't think my question was clear at all reading over it (Im very tired). Ideally I am looking at how to make that particular string bold as well as display the rest of the strings

Comment: You can use NSAttributedString class and NSAttributedText property for that

Comment: @MidhunMP instead of what is suggested below or within the if loop?

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone: That answer is correct, for making bold you need to use the above things inside the if block of that code. Also check [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring)

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone: With pleasure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only will this get you directly to each instance within the array that contains the text you're searching for, but it will also perform significantly better than the code in the question.

```
for (NSString *testWord in legislationArray) {
    if ([testWord rangeOfString:@"BOLDME"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // testWord contains "BOLDME"
        cell.dynamicTextView.text = 
            [cell.dynamicTextView.text stringByAppendingString:testWord];
    }
}
```

As written, this will append the found string to whatever text is already in the text view.  It may be that you only want one word in the text view.  If this is the case, then you should `break;` as soon as you find the first one.

Comment: perfect.I will accept when it lets me. I must be real tired to of overlooked some of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over NSArray and check each string if it contains specific word:

```
for(NSString *value in array) {
    if([value rangeOfString:word] != NSNotFound) { 
        /* we have found that string*/ 
     }
}
```