# Bold word of a sentence of NSString in Xcode

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have an issue in display sentence with a bold selected word.

```
NSString * string = @"Notes on iOS7 going to take a <-lot-> of getting used to!";
```

I want to print a sentence like this:

"Notes on iOS7 going to take a **lot** of getting used to!"

A plus that I have this code to select "lot" word. So how to base on this selected to bold the word. This string in this is example. So the range would be different.

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=<-).*?(?=->)"
                                                                       options:0 error:&error];
if (regex) {
    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
        NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];

        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    }
} else {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

It will be:

Before: Notes on iOS7 going to take a <-lot-> of getting used to!

After: Notes on iOS7 going to take a **lot** of getting used to!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where you want to print?

Comment: I want put the string into a label. Tks.

Comment: You attributedString property of UILabel.

Comment: Thanks i have search this attributedString. But have stuck at apply bold specify font.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `NSAttributedString` for that. Have a look at [Any way to bold part of a NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring)

Comment: Thanks so much. But I have stuck with bold selected word in sentence as above.