# How to format some text as bold within a UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have an iOS UILabel that needs some of the text to be normal and some of the text to be bold. The bold text is actually supposed to be a link to another part of the app, but for now, I'm just reacting to tapping on the entire label. How can I format some of the text to be bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `attributedText` property:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is a test."];
[text addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
          value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
label.attributedText = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSAttributedString. Please look at this answer to see an example: [Any way to bold part of a NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring)